# "Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit"

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am adding `WebView` on test script. Then I encountered this error upon running test.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit

      at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:181:21)
```

Here's my test

```
test('should render correctly', () => {
  const navigation = {} as unknown as RootStackProps<'WEBVIEW'>['navigation'];
  const route = {
    params: {
      url: '**some url**',
    },
  } as unknown as RootStackProps<'WEBVIEW'>['route'];

  renderWithProviders(<WebView navigation={navigation} route={route} />);
});
```

What should I change on the test script?